# set the footer at page bottom

Tags: html, css

This is a test code but I need to set the footer on the real bottom of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
                <?php
                    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
                        echo $i."<br>";
                    }
                ?>
        </div>
        <footer>
            Footer<br>
        </footer>
    </body>
<html>
```

and the css file

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -20%;
    padding-bottom: -20%;
    background-color: green;
}
footer {
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

That way set the footer on the page bottom but if you scroll the page continues,I need to set the footer at the real end,when you cannot scroll anymore  there is where the footer has to be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this... this sets it after all content which is what I think you mean

```
footer {
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Have a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7grcmceh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to the footer element:

```
footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the margin and padding for the body, there is a default margin and padding, you can remove this.

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/y05Lej92/1/)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```